# Why am I getting Postgresql Deadlock when performance testing with apache benchmarking?

Tags: python, apache, postgresql, psycopg2, database-deadlocks

I'm using the following.

> 1. Postgresql - version 9.5
> 2. Flask web framework
> 3. Pgbouncer - lightweight connection pooler for PostgreSQL.
> 4. psycopg2 - version 2.7

My API's were working fine, until I tested the performance using apache bench marking using psycog2 cursors.

The transactions are:

```
cursor.execute("select id from table where product_name='xyz' limit 1 for update");
```

using the `id` from above I do the following:

```
cursor.execute('update table set locked_time=<time> where id=<id_from_above>')
```

and finally I'm doing commit using:

conn.commit()

where `conn` is pyscopg2 connection object

The schema for  the table looks like this:

```
    Column   |           Type           | Modifiers 
-------------+--------------------------+----------- 
 id          | interger                 | not null default nextval('table_id_seq'::regclass) 
 locked_time | timestamp with time zone | not null
 cust_id     | integer                  | 
Indexes:
    "table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "table_cust_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES customer(id)
```

I am testing the performace using apache benchmarking `ab` as:

```
ab -n500 -c40 <API>
```

What could be the possible reason for getting deadlock.
Also, if I decrease the concurrency while testing with `ab` like:

```
ab -n500 -c10.
```

Deadlock:

```
TransactionRollbackError: deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 18938 waits for ShareLock on transaction 107698; blocked by process 18950.
Process 18950 waits for ShareLock on transaction 107701; blocked by process 18938.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (19671,40) in relation "table"
```

Comment: Are there any foreign keys defined on the table?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've added the table schema description. `"table_cust_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES customer(id)`

Comment: Thanks. It makes things harder that you change around names (e.g., your statements would fail if `table` were not surrounded by double quotes, so it can't be the real name, or there is no column `product_name` in your definition). Such things can easily mask problems. Could you try the following: From `psql`, first run `BEGIN;`, then your `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;`, then `SELECT * FROM pg_locks WHERE pid = pg_backend_pid();` and then `ROLLBACK;`. Post the `pg_locks` query result and the result of `SELECT <number>::regclass;` for every `<number>` under `relation`.